# Weblogic Configuration - prefer-web-inf-classes

Tags: weblogic

prefer-web-inf-classes has to be specified for the classes specified in Web-INF to take precendence over classes present in application library of weblogic server. I have a special case where I need the class loader to use one specific jar from WEB-INF folder. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Is this class an open source or 3rd party jar or your custom class? I'm wondering whether this class alone needs to be in the WEB-INF or can not the whole jar (including your class) be loaded from App classloader?

Comment: Hi Jose,the specific jar is apache-commons-lang. I am sorry - it is a jar and not a class. Is there a way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Not only for one jar from web-inf. The solution in this case is mgaert's answer. Move all other if possible into APP-INF and keep this one with a prefer-web-inf, else use package level entry in application.xml (i.e. Filtering Classloader)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at [Filtering Classloaders](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/programming/classloading.html#wp1097187)?

This allows to specify on a package-by-package level just which classloader to use.

You want to be *very* careful with this, though. Are you sure you already *are* in CLassloader Hell, so you *must* resort to this kind of stuff, and there's really no alternative?

Did you consider putting the JAR into the `APP-INF/lib` folder of your EAR? Or move *"all but the one you need in WEB-INF/lib"* out to APP-INF/lib?

Comment: Thanks mgaert. I just have a war file and it is not bundled into to ear. Is it possible to have filtering classloaders specify specific packages in WEB-INF\lib?

Answer (score 5):

To prefer all packages which are in your WEB-INF/lib over those which are bundled with your WebLogic lib set `<prefer-web-inf-classes>` to true in your `weblogic.xml` or `application-weblogic.xml`.

```
<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
```

For more detail see Using a Filtering Classloader, weblogic.xml Deployment Descriptor Elements and WebLogic's ClassLoaders, Filtering ClassLoader and ClassLoader Analysis Tool .

If you are not sure if the right class is loaded you can use the Classloader Analysis Tool for WebLogic.

Comment: For some reason the ClassLoader Analysis Tool (CAT) does not work. I receive an HTTP 503 error. I noticed the necessary wls-cat.war file is not included in the managed server deployment/installation like other managed servers on the weblogic container. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Weblogic 10.3.4+ version. You can use [prefer-application-packages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#autoId24) to control class level preference loading. Take a look at [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ArLTKapjV_8#t=306s) video for more details.