# NetBeans taking JSF Server library instead of registered libraries

Tags: jsf, netbeans, weblogic

I have an Enterprise Application (EAR) with this specs:

- JAVA EE 5
- JDK 6
- JSF 2
- Running on Weblogic 11g(10.3.6)

I have a WAR inside of it, the weblogic server has JSF libraries but i want the libraries i already provided. The problem is when i add JSF Framework in Project Properties and then i click Registered Libraries (not server library) it seems like it takes it but after a few seconds when i click Project Properties/ Frameworks it says again : "Server Library".

I really need to use the registered libraries.

What can i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to set the following in your weblogic.xml file:

```
<weblogic-web-app>
    <container-descriptor>
       <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

You can find more information here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm

[Weblogic Configuration - prefer-web-inf-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166580/weblogic-configuration-prefer-web-inf-classes)