# How do I override the classpath for an application instead of appending to it?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

Our install script adds some pre-lib libraries to the classpath for starting our
web services, such that the classpath looks like this in the admin console:

> /u01/app/oracle/middleware/user_projects/domains/RadiusStudioDomain/prelib/eclipselink-2.4.1.jar:/u01/app/oracle/middleware/user_projects/domains/RadiusStudioDomain/prelib/javax.persistence-2.0.4.v201112161009.jar:/u01/app/oracle/middleware/user_projects/domains/RadiusStudioDomain/prelib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/u01/app/oracle/middleware/user_projects/domains/RadiusStudioDomain/prelib/commonj.sdo-2.1.1.v201112051852.jar:/u01/app/oracle/middleware/patch_wls1036/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar:/u01/app/oracle/middleware/patch_ocp371/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar:/u01/tools/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/tools.jar:/u01/app/oracle/middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic_sp.jar:/u01/app/oracle/middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/u01/app/oracle/middleware/modules/features/weblogic.server.modules_10.3.6.0.jar:/u01/app/oracle/middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/webservices.jar:/u01/app/oracle/middleware/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.1/lib/ant-all.jar:/u01/app/oracle/middleware/modules/net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b2/lib/ant-contrib.jar

However, instead of replacing the classpath, this get appended to the existing classpath,
which is wrong. Is it possible in the configuration of my server to check a box saying
I want to override not append to the classpath?

Comment: Weblogic is including the classpath that is created via commEnv.sh, setDomainEnv.sh, and startWebLogic.sh. What errors are you seeing? You may need to prefer your classes over the defaults: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816632/netbeans-taking-jsf-server-library-instead-of-registered-libraries/19818913#19818913

Comment: The problem is that the web-service classpath was added by our installer to consist of the prelib modules, followed by the WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH set from the scripts. Unfortunately when the web service starts, and we dump out the classpath into our admin console, it consists of WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH follwed by our classpath. The standard weblogic classpath contains an older version of commons-lang. We need the classpath when the web-service starts to be the classpath defined for the web-service. It needs to override rather than append to the exisiting classpath.

Comment: Ok then I definitely think you can use link I provided above, start looking at making your web-service "prefer" the classes you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is being caused by the following property

```
StartScriptEnabled=true
```

in the **nodemanager.properties** file for WebLogic. If this property is set to false, then the classpath in my application are used instead.